# I tried to add an object in a mutable array, but it displayed an error

Tags: objective-c

```
        char name;
    NSMutableArray * student = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (int i=0;i<3; i++)
    {
        NSLog(@"Add the name of student number", i+1);
        scanf("%s",&name);
        [student addObject:@name];
    }
    NSLog(@"The names you entered are\n");
    for(int i= 0; i<3; i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", [student objectAtIndex:i]);
    }
```

It doesn't let me add the name to the array, thus making an error in addobject and makes the program only save nul. Can you help me?

Comment: You should consider accepting one of the answers to help others, who find this later, understand what works.  I suggest accepting @CRD 's which also provides a better way to get a `char` from user input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems, first:

```
char name;
...
scanf("%s",&name);
```

This will more than likely write all over your memory causing a problem sooner or later. You have defined `name` as a `char` variable – it holds a single character – and then you pass its address to `scanf` as though it was the address of a string – which in C is an *array* of characters. The `scanf` function will happily write the first character of the string into `name`, the second over whatever follows it in memory, etc.

You need to declare `name` something like:

```
char name[MAX_STRING_SIZE+1];
```

and then the easiest what to read in the string is probably to use `fgets`:

```
fgets(name, MAX_STRING_SIZE, stdin);
```

as this ensures you won't exceed your buffer size.

Your next problem is you try to convert your C string to an `NSString` using `@name` – which is wrong it should be `@(name)`. However even that while valid won't do what you expect: as `name` is a char, which is integral type in C, this will produce you an `NSNumber`.

To convert the C String into an `NSString` use the `NSString` method `initWithCString:encoding:`.

HTH

Comment: Might be worth adding, to get just the first char input (which seems to be the OP's aim), write a null, `name[1] = 0;` before passing it to the NSString constructor.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to "box" a char as an `NSString` is to use the `stringWithFormat:` constructor.

```
// replace [student addObject:@name]; which contains a syntax error
NSString *nameString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", name];
[student addObject:nameString];
```

Comment: Agreed, @user3182143.  Thanks.  See my comment on the OP.